# How to get correct user?

Tags: python, django, view, model, display

How i can take a correct user?

Let's assume I have a model named "MUSIC" in which it is located

```
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have a page on which i want display everything that is in the model "MUSIC".

Views

```
m = Music.objects.all()
```

Okay i know that this display all project music. But the problem is how to assign the specific user from model named "Profile" to model named 'Music"

Url

```
path('profil_user/<int:pk>/',ShowProfilPage.as_view(), name='profil_user'),
```

When i try:

```
{% for x in m %}
  {{x}}
  <a href="{% url 'profil_user' x.pk %}> CLICK </a>
{% endfor %}
```

This take not a correct user profile but it doesn't get to the model called 'Profile' but to 'Music'

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/profil_user/2/
```

it is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/profil_user/10/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/profil_user/11/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is pass the profil pk instead of the music one.

```
{% for x in m %}
  {{x}}
  <a href="{% url 'profil_user' x.owner.pk %}> CLICK </a>
  # <a href="{% url 'profil_user' x.owner.id %}> CLICK </a> # another way
{% endfor %}
```

This way it gets the pk from profil related to the music being displayed